# Best way to apply a two-dimensional function in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I often find myself applying two dimensional functions in `numpy`. I have done it several different ways, however, none seem to be very elegant. Is there a "correct" way to do the following in `numpy`?

```
import numpy as np

X = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
Y = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

mg = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
zipped = np.c_[mg[0].ravel(), mg[1].ravel()]

def harmonic_avg(row):
    return 2 * row[0] * row[1] / (row[0] + row[1])

result = np.apply_along_axis(harmonic_avg, 1, zipped)

result.reshape(100,100)
```

Comment: `apply_along_axis` is not a performance tool.  It's slower than for loops.  It can make nested loops prettier, but that's about it.  I wouldn't try anything fancy to make it work.

Comment: Are you kidding me?? I've been using that for years thinking it was just as fast! Thank you for letting me know — I have some code to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the most elegant way would imho be using the meshgrids directly

```
result = 2*mg[0]*mg[1]/(mg[0]+mg[1])
```

Or as a function

```
def harmonic_avg(mg):
    return 2*mg[0]*mg[1]/(mg[0]+mg[1])
result = harmonic_avg(mg)
```